# C# Outlook 2007 - How do I access attachment contents directly from my addin?

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-2007

I'm trying to parse text-based file attachments (txt, doc, etc...).  However, I can't seem to get to the binary information itself.  I can get the filename and I can save the file out to some temporary folder and open it from there, but that seems messy.

Is there any way to access the content of an attachment without saving it, reading it, then deleting it or am I just chasing my tail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Redemption will help you here, SafeMailItem.Attachments collection has Attachment object that has a property "AsText"
check out

http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/

76mel

Comment: Except for the $199 license fee that seems great.  I'll have to see if I can spare the cash for it.

Comment: Redemption is the only nice way as it a wrapper around extended MAPI and take out the complexity.

Answer (score 3):

You can get content of an attachment using Microsoft schema -

```
   private void GetAttachmentContent(Attachments attachments)
    {
        foreach (Attachment attachment in attachments)
        {
            //microsoft schema to get the attachment content
            string AttachSchema = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x37010102";
            byte[] filebyte = (byte[])attachment.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty(AttachSchema);
        }
    }
```

You need to ref : Microsoft.CSharp.dll in code file

Comment: PropertyAccessor.GetProperty will fail for the large binary (such as PR_ATTACH_DATA_BIN) properties. On the MAPI level (C++ or Delphi)PR_ATTACH_DATA_BIN would have to be opened as IStream using ISAttach::OpenProperty. PropertyAccessor does not do that.

Comment: Can you specify large binary means what is size it will not cope up with?

Comment: It is store provider dependent. For online Exchange store, it can be as low as 32kB.