# Read Outlook attachment content in Outlook add-in (C# ) while creating a mail

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-2007

I am trying to develop an outlook add-in in VS 2010. It's purpose is to scan email body and attachment content for some key words and if any such words are found, email sending should be blocked. 
I am able to read email body and subject and to the validation but I am not understanding how to read an attachment content (txt file) while composing the mail.

attachment.GetTemporaryPath() is not giving the attachment path. I guess this works only for mails in inbox. 
One way I found was saving the attachment to a temp folder and reading it (attachment.saveAs()). 
Is this the only way  to read attachment content while composing a mail ?

Possible Duplicate : [C# Outlook 2007 - How do I access attachment contents directly from my addin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/827131/c-sharp-outlook-2007-how-do-i-access-attachment-contents-directly-from-my-addi)

But as suggested in there, I cant use Redemption. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, saving the attachment data to a temporary file and reading it s the only way. In theory, you can use `Attachment.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty` to read the `PR_ATTACH_DATA_BIN` property, but you will run into problems for the large (> 64kB) files.

You can also use Extended MAPI to open the attachment data as `IStream` (`IAttach::OpenProperty(PR_ATTACH_DATA_BIN, IID_IStream)`), but it is only accessible through C++ or Delphi. You can use [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/) (any language - I am its author) that wraps Extended MAPI and exposes `AsArray` and `AsText` properties on both [RDOAttachment](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOAttachment.htm) and the [Attachment](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/safe_Attachment.htm) object exposed by the `Safe*Item` objects.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will try PropertyAccessor.GetProperty  method.